# How to change button text in Payload CMS

Tags: typescript, payload-cms

I want to change the button text from 'Publish Changes' into 'Publish Data' in the Payload CMS but can't find any file where it contain the button style that i can edit

is anyone know how to change the button name? Thank you

[image: change the button name]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to swap in a new react component in order to override the text.

The documentation for swapping out collection components is here: https://payloadcms.com/docs/admin/components#collections. You would specifically swap out the `PublishButton`.

You can also find the default publish button to modify here: https://github.com/payloadcms/payload/blob/main/packages/payload/src/admin/components/elements/Publish/index.tsx